# Standard for DC connectors?

Tags: connector

Is there a standard for DC power connectors for 12V solar systems?

I am familar with Molex connectors, but they seem more suitable for internal connections, not something that would be outside of a housing.

- Indoor
- 20-amp maximum

Comment: There like tens of thousands of different connectors for different environments and different electrical characteristics..

Comment: what is the current??

Comment: Is this for outdoor, 4-season use?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am asking about standards, not particular connectors.

Comment: @TylerDurden OK, but it is not obvious from the question, perhaps you should clarify it. Take a look at [IP rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code)

Comment: BTW, solar system is not the same as solar-powered system..

Answer (score 1):

There are specific connectors for solar panels. A quick search shows [these](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2060353.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xsolar%20panel%20connectors.TRS0&_nkw=solar%20panel%20connectors&_sacat=0), which are good up to 30A.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all the newer solar panels are using MC4 connectors (for grid-tie installations). Seems like it would also be a good choice for 12V systems, unless the current is higher than 20A.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MC4_connector